# How do I convert this SQL query into hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Can someone please tell me how to convert this SQL query into hibernate?

```
SELECT * FROM sys_quote_master AS g1
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT order_base_id, order_id FROM sys_quote_master
   GROUP BY order_base_id, order_date_last_revised 
   ORDER BY order_date_last_revised desc) AS g2
ON g2.order_id = g1.order_id;
```

Basically,

I have tried this and it doesn't work:

```
DetachedCriteria crit1 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(QuoteMaster.class);
ProjectionList pList = Projections.projectionList();
pList.add(Projections.groupProperty("orderBaseId"));
session = HibernateSessionFactory.currentSession();
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(QuoteMaster.class);
Criteria c = crit.createCriteria("QuoteMaster", CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN);
c.setProjection(pList);
```

I get this error:

**org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: this of:
 QuoteMaster**

And I think it has to do with this line of code were I am trying to create an inner join to the same table:

```
Criteria c = crit.createCriteria("QuoteMaster", CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN);
```

So basically, my question is 'How to create a join to the same table using Criteria.createCriteria or Criteria.createAlias?'  The doc for Criteria class states the first parameter is a dot-separated property path, but what the heck does that mean?  :)

Every example I found so far shows how to do this with 2 or 3 tables but not to the same table and I have no idea what to use for the first argument.

Comment: What have you tried? Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you or explain how to write the code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and any error messages you receive. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page and [this advice on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hello there, I updated the original post with more info.

Comment: That's leaps and bounds better. I'm retracting my close vote and upvoting. BTW, backticks are for inline code spans (within descriptive text). Code on separate lines should be placed in code blocks (indent by 4 or highlight and click th `{}` symbol. Block quotes are good for error messages (add `>` at the beginning of the line)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how your entities are, this should give rough idea.

```
from SystQuoteMasterEntity sqm join ( select sqm1.orderbaseid, sqm1.orderId from SystQuoteMasterEntity sqm1 group by orderbaseid,orderdatelastrev order by orderdatelast desc) g2
```

Comment: See my update up in the original problem - I don't have a whole lot of experience in hibernate, hence the reason I asked my question, as I was trying to learn the correct way to do this and can't seem to find any good examples.

Comment: Thanks Zeus, but isn't that just sql again?  Basically, I am trying to  use Criteria to do this.  Is that possible?  If so, how do you do it?